# How to allocate memory when declaring String in Rust

Tags: rust, memory, compiler-construction

When declaring the String type, I have a question about how memory is allocated in the stack and heap areas.

I think, the memory allocation image would be below.

```rust
let s = String::from("hello world");
```

```
(A)                                                (B)            
+======================+----- static memory -------+======================+ 
|          ...         |                           | "hello world"(12)    |
|                      |                           |          ...         |
+======================+------ stack memory -------+======================+
| s(24)                |                           | s(24)                |
| data addr            |                           | data addr            |
| length               |                           | length               |
| capacity             |                           | capacity             |
|          ...         |                           |          ...         |
|                      |                           |                      |
|          ...         |                           |                      |
| "hello world"(12)    |                           |          ...         |
+======================+------- heap memory -------+======================+
```

Which scenario is correct?

I understand that literal strings are stored in static area during compile time. However, the Rust documentation states that the String type is equivalent to Vec. The Vec type stores all its elements on the heap, so I'm confused as to whether scenario A is correct.

Comment: Neither scenario is correct, because when you create the `String` you copy the string literal's contents from static memory onto the heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither is correct.

First off, `"hello world"` is only 11 bytes. Rust does not null-terminate strings.

Essentially, `"hello world"` is a `str` stored in the binary's static memory, which is copied from static memory into heap memory. The `String` struct stores a pointer to the heap memory, the length of the string, and the capacity of the allocation.

pseudo-code:

```
static_memory = {
  contents: str = "hello world"=
  lit: &str = (&contents, 11)
}

def String_from_strref(text: &str) -> String:
  (pointer, length) = text
  heap_pointer = malloc(length)
  capacity = memcpy(heap_pointer, pointer, length)
  
  return (heap_pointer, length, capacity)

let s = String_from_strref(lit)
```

And after that executes, memory will look like:

```
=== stack memory ===+=== heap memory ===+===== static memory =====
 s(24)              |                   |          "hello world"
   pointer ----------> "hello world..." |          ^
   length = 11      |                   | lit(16)  |
   capacity >= 11   |                   |   pointer
                    |                   |   length = 11
```

Note: order of fields is for educational purposes only and not guaranteed by the layout of the various types

Comment: Thank you for answer. The question has been clearly resolved.

Comment: I don't think you meant that, but from your pseudocode and chart it seems like the `&str` (the pointer) itself is stored in static memory, which is not.

Comment: *lowers glasses over nose*: Actually, son, since "hello world" is only 11 bytes, it is not encoded in static data memory as such, but encoded directly into the instruction stream. Which is a form of static memory. But nevertheless.